# How can I create a filter on Google sheets to filter only words that begin with uppercase?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I have a column with 2 kind of words:

1. words without uppercase (**b**etrachtet) and
2. words that begin with uppercase (**A**nalysieren)

I need a filter that shows my only those words which begin with uppercase.

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community User 13 times.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `=filter` function, you can try this :

```
=FILTER(A1:A15;REGEXMATCH(A1:A15;"[A-Z].*?"))
```

[image]

---

**Note** : Depending on your language settings, you can replace `;` with `,`